# SQL Server index help performance?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, database-indexes

I have run the Database Engines Tuning Advisor in Sql Server 2008 R2, then there are a few indexes that it suggested me to create, so I created them. The question is, in what way that I can check if these indexes are helping the DB performance ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running an explain plan on the queries that are performed in your application. They should show a relatively low query cost.

You could drop the indexes again, run the original explain plan statements to compare the performance before and after adding the index.

Comment: That actually came naturally when I was thinking how to do it and now I can confirm. Since I am not a DBA, I was just wondering was there any other ways how people do this. Thank you:)